# Libvirt Build Failure On Fedora 17 After Update

Tags: qemu, libvirt

I recently installed the updates for Fedora 17, among which was an upgrade from Linux Kernel 3.7.x to 3.8.x.  Now I can't build Libvirt!  It is giving me this error:

```
checking linux/if_bridge.h usability... no
checking linux/if_bridge.h presence... yes
configure: WARNING: linux/if_bridge.h: present but cannot be compiled
configure: WARNING: linux/if_bridge.h:     check for missing prerequisite headers?
configure: WARNING: linux/if_bridge.h: see the Autoconf documentation
configure: WARNING: linux/if_bridge.h:     section "Present But Cannot Be Compiled"
configure: WARNING: linux/if_bridge.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------- ##
configure: WARNING:     ## Report this to libvir-list redhat com ##
configure: WARNING:     ## ------------------------------------- ##
checking for linux/if_bridge.h... no
```

How can I fix this so I can build Libvirt again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the build failure was being caused by the header file `/usr/include/linux/if_bridge.h`.  Fortunately the fix is quite easy (once you know what to do).

1. Open `/usr/include/linux/if_bridge.h` in a text editor
2. Add this include line, `#include <netinet/ip6.h>`
3. Rebuild

You will have to reapply this fix each time you boot into a different kernel version since the `/usr/include/linux/` header files are wiped out.